# Not able to rewrite the pagination URL for the posts

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination

My posts pagination in not working in WordPress 5.5 and So, I want to rewrite the URL for the pagination. **I am using posts with pagination in the inner page with slug "post".**

```
Current URL (The Pagination): domain.com/blog/2

I want to change the URL to: domain.com/blog/page/2
```

By changing the URL, the posts pagination start working. I added the jQuery code and the pagination is working but how I can do that in WordPress.

**My code added in functions.php:**

```
function my_pagination_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('blog/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?page=blog&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_pagination_rewrite');
```

But this is not working.

**I also tried the code using jQuery and it is working:**

```
<script>
    jQuery('.elementor-pagination').find('a').each(function() {
    
    var url=jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var pieces = url.split("/");
    
    var newhrf =window.location.origin+'/blog/page/'+pieces[4];
    jQuery(this).attr('href',newhrf);
});
</script>
```

The jQuery code ia working but my code in `functions.php` is not working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Seems to be related to: WordPress stripping out "page" query parameter with 301 redirect.

See Make WordPress Core ticket 50976:

"We understand that it may be annoying for themes and plugins authors to fix their usage of this variable, but it would introduce a way more issues if it was changed on WordPress Core side. It's objectively better to get this fixed on plugins and themes since it is a wrong usage of WordPress variables.

Closing this as wontfix, as the issue shouldn't be fixed on WordPress core but rather on plugins and themes side."